# Where is the default type specified if the target type of a lambda can't be inferred?

Tags: java, lambda, higher-order-functions

Let's say I have a higher order function which takes in a generic predicate object:

```
public static <E> void foo(Predicate<E> predicate) {...}
```

I can call that method like this even though the type of x aswell as the target type of the Predicate is unclear:

```
foo(x -> x != null);
```

Compiling and running this is no problem because somewhere someone just defaults the type of x to Object.
Why is the type just being defaulted (as opposed to maybe just not letting it compile in the first place)  or where is this behaviour specified?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say whether my own answer is completely correct but this is what I found:

JLS chapter 18.1.13:

> When inference begins, a bound set is typically generated from a list of type parameter declarations P1, ..., Pp and associated inference variables α1, ..., αp. Such a bound set is constructed as follows. For each l (1 ≤ l ≤ p):

> If Pl has no TypeBound, the bound αl <: Object appears in the set.

(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.1.3)

I don't fully understand how the resolution process afterwards works but I assume since we only have one bound in our set
{α <: Object}
α (and in our case x) will be resolved to Object.
(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.4)